# How could I open a WebPage inside my Flutter WebApp and parse the URI of this webpage?

Tags: flutter, webview, payment-gateway, flutter-web-browser

Does someone know how to open a "WebView" inside a Flutter WebApp ? I need to parse the url of a webpage an return this result into mu Flutter Web App

below my code that open a new tab in the browser :

```
html.window.open('https://demo.vivapayments.com/web2?ref=$orderCode&lang=fr-BE',"_blank");
```

I'm Using VivaWallet Payment Solutions and I need to parse the URL after payment validation before sending the items in my database...

I need a solution for Friday night , please if someone has an idea ...

I also tried HTMLWIDGET :

[image]

but it doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open webview you can use [fwfh_webview](https://pub.dev/packages/fwfh_webview) package. But what you want to achieve is use the **$orderCode** response and parse it to VivaWallet API Url.

just change this

**html.window.open('https://demo.vivapayments.com/web2?ref=$orderCode&lang=fr-BE',"_blank");**

to

**html.window.open('https://demo.vivapayments.com/web2?ref=$orderCode&lang=fr-BE',"new tab");**

It will open you a new tab for vivapayment where you do your transaction. wait on app screen to finish transaction.
then you should create a transaction table/collection whether with its status whether it is successfull or not because you should keep record of failure transaction too.
Rest you can do on the transaction status basis.

Comment: I need to parse the uri where there is the parameter named « k » that I have to check after having the order code, order code is just a order request

Comment: I’ll try your solution but I need to keep access to the new tab url

Comment: I don't see the difference between _blank and new tab... Despite I've test both of them....